# garage door usually won't close - even trolley without door won't move much

Tags: garage-door

I'm having a problem with my Lift Master Forumla I Whisper Drive garage door opener.

For the last few weeks, the door has frequently stopped part-way down when closing and then gone back up again.  Now, for the last couple of days, the door will not go down at all -- at most it goes down a couple of inches, and then triggers to come back up.  This happens *most* of the time -- sometimes it will just randomly work.

If I detach the door, I have the same problem with just the trolley. Most of the time, it will just go a couple of inches and then halt and go back.

I've done the following so far:

- maxed out the downward KG pressure -- no effect
- checked the sensors -- they seem to be fine (and anyway, I get some movement from the door)
- same results from the wall button and the remote
- pulled the cover off and visually inspected -- nothing that immediately jumps out as a problem. Also, no smell or noise or anything that I notice when this is happening.
- tightened the "chain" (it's really a rubber belt with teeth) -- no effect

Any thoughts of what might be going on?  I'm really hoping I don't have to call a pro.

thanks in advance.

Comment: If you operate the door manually does the *door* work?

Comment: Yes.  It goes up and down easily on the track when I do it by hand.

Comment: Sounds like maybe a gear (or other part of the mechanism), might be getting bound up.  Remove the cover, and run the opener.  Watch any moving parts closely, keeping any eye out for anything that looks like it's binding, jamming, slipping, etc.  Be careful not to get your hands, or other body parts into the mechanism or anything electrical. Make sure you also inspect the cog at the end of the track (near the door), to make sure it is spinning freely.  Check the track itself, to make sure the trolley is not getting stuck.

Comment: After the door returns to the open position, do the lights on the unit flash?

Comment: When you removed the cover, did you notice any plastic shavings/dust inside?

Comment: Yes, the lights flash after it comes back.

Comment: Did not notice any shavings/dust inside the cover

Comment: I ran it earlier without the cover and didn't immediately notice anything, but will try again and also try your other suggestions

Comment: Visually inspect the drive gear, to make sure it's not worn down

Comment: If the opener only moves a few inches, it could be a bad RPM sensor.

Comment: The unit uses a [hall effect sensor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hall_effect_sensor) to determine the motors speed.  If the speed is not within a certain range, the opener moves back to a safe position.  You'll find the sensor on the drive shaft on the front (back?) of the motor (opposite the worm gear).  It's made up of a cap, and circuit board. Make sure the cap is properly positioned, and that any wires are firmly attached to the circuit board.

Comment: Make sure you have no binding anywhere along the travel of the trolley. I had to reset mine by unplugging the unit from electrical outlet. I unplugged it and left it for a day (I didn't need into the garage anyway), plugged it back in and it reset. Works fine. So try that. It usually doesn't reset your remotes, but if it does, you can re-learn them quickly.

Comment: So the same problem started up again tonight. I did some more looking and comparing with my other openers. I noticed that on the bottom part of the trolley, there is a small metal sheet that hooks into the bottom of the trolley with 2 small flaps on either side and sits between the trolley and the track it sits on. It looks like it’s there to stabilize the trolley as it rises.  Anyway, two of those flaps are missing so one side of that sheet moves freely. It looks like that might be causing the trolley to lurch more as it’s going and maybe set off the sensor. I’ll try to post a picture.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did not state the actual model number so I will not be able to answer with model specific information that would be much more detailed and specific to your situation. So you will not be able to do this blind folded.

Since your sensors are working .. good. Some movement of the door is not an indication they are working - that is an indication they are clear to start with. You could have a loose wire or sensor or circuit board inside the senor that when the Door Moves the vibration causes the beam to break! - been there done that.

[Why do the lights on my garage door opener flash and my door will not close](http://support.liftmaster.com/articles/How_To/Why-do-the-lights-on-my-garage-door-opener-flash-and-my-door-will-not-close-1484145609322/)

[How to align safety reversing sensors.](http://support.liftmaster.com/articles/How_To/How-to-align-safety-reversing-sensors-1484145609323)

So if those sensors are Truly fine.

Then check your drive gear, it has a set screw or some means of securing it to the drive shaft that screw may have backed out and or is loose. The gear may turn with no load (in other words no belt connected) but might spin free if there is a load - Remove the belt and you can try to grab the drive gear by hand and hold it from turning while the unit runs. Your motor appears to have a gear box and the belt pulley attached - this style pulley if I am not mistaken is a compression style - so it might not have a set screw but rather the way it is secured causes a compressing effect and the pulley grabs the shaft - in short tighten the pulley to the shaft (it is most likely loose) as I said previous Make / Model number / perhaps picture of the name plate .. might have yielded you detailed pictures and specifics to what you have and you might have had it fixed in less than a minute..

Comment: I went and jiggled everything - including the sensors, and now it seems to be working just fine again.  You may be right that it was the sensors shaking out of alignment.  Fingers crossed that it keeps working.  thanks for the help!

Comment: @FerrisJones Sensors could be the wires are loose (even internally) or that they jiggled out of alignment during door movement. You can modify your mounting system to mount them more rigidly to the wall - some mount on the door track and I think this is a bad thing - they tend to flex and loosen over time.

Comment: The problem reappeared, and I posted another more detailed question here: https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/138562/garage-door-wont-close-sometimes